# Typescript get type constructor of each arguments of a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, annotations, static-typing

I have seen TypeScript libraries that by just add an annotation on the class, it is capable of injecting this class into the constructor of other class by just declaring the argument type.

It goes something like this:

```
@someAnnotation()
class Foo {
}

@someAnnotation()
class Bar {
}

@someAnnotation()
class A {
    constructor(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) {
    }
}

@someAnnotation()
class B {
    constructor(a: A) {
    }
}
```

Then magically, the libary can somehow get these

```
/// how do they get these? 
const constructorArgumentsTypesOfA = [Foo, Bar]
const constructorArgumentsTypesOfB = [A]
```

How is this possible ? What is the code behind the annotation

An example of this library is `typedi`

Comment: So the code for `typedi` is openly available... Why not take a peek? https://github.com/typestack/typedi/tree/develop/src/decorators

Comment: Those are called decorators not annotations. Annotations were a feature proposed and subsequently scrapped from ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code of typedi, I found that they use a library called `reflect-metadata`

And the job is done like this

```
const paramTypes = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', A);
console.log(paramTypes)
```

To be more specific, `import 'reflect-metadata'` must be called before anything else.

Also, the decorator is required. But any would work, even an empty function decorator

```
function Service(target: any) {

}
```

Used like this

```
@Service
class A {
    id = 'A'

    constructor(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) {
    }
}
```